# For Binary words v,w is d(v,w)=wt(v-w)=wt(v+w)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

I found this in my discrete math lecture notes on error correcting codes, and was immediately confused as this should obviously be wrong.  I even found a counterexample: v=101, w=010.  Here v-w=011 so wt(v-w)=2, but v+w=0111 so wt(v+w)=3.  I'm not sure what could be wrong about this counterexample.  I am probably missing something.

This is probably very elementary, but I am scared to discredit something my professor had no problem telling her class whilst studying for a final.  And, if this is true, what can be said about this "counterexample"?

Comment: I suspect that $v-w$ and $v+w$ are meant to be performed element-wise, modulo 2, without borrowing/carrying. Are those operations defined in your lecture notes?

Comment: @Joe Sorry! I probably should have included the notes' justification: "You should note that, since we are working in a product of copies of B (in which +1=-1), every element is its own additive inverse and so, v-w=v+w.  Hence d(v,w)=wt(v+w)"

What you said makes sense then, although I was never told that "+" did not refer to standard addition, which is interesting

Comment: So Joe's comment clinches it. Bitstrings are being regarded as bit vectors mod $2$, not numbers. Thus for your proposed test case, you should have $v+w=v-w=111$.